# Could the world function as "normal" if the rich, famous, and a certain percentage of each country left the planet?

Tags: internal-consistency, technological-development, near-future, population

My story is about a radio intern who is left in charge of the station after a few ships carrying a chunk of the Earth's population leave while claiming that the ships will be sent back for the rest of them once they discover a better planet. Most of the people unlucky enough not to be chosen for the first voyage (if you couldn't pay your way on, you had to have minimal "genetic defects" and be willing and able to have children and even then that didn't guarantee you a spot) understand that this isn't true, due to the fact that even if they do send a ship back, they'll all be dead by then and it'll be their descendants getting on the ships.

Since many of the remaining population on Earth is working-class,  would they be able to keep the world running similar to how it is now, or would they need to treat the world like it was in a past time, only focusing on the essentials like light and radio but being able to power things such as mobile phones with solar chargers? Very few politicians stayed behind, so the governmental structure wouldn't be the same, but this is working on the assumption that most of those left behind just want to try and go on with their normal lives.

Their reasons for leaving were due to threats of supernatural occurrences, but only the governments of the world were aware of it. The rest of humanity was just lead to believe they didn't want to stay around for the effects of climate change, so the threats have no effect on the remaining population yet.

Long story short, if they knew who was going to leave beforehand, could the world still function like it does in 2020 (minus covid) and if not, what point in time would the diminished population be closest resource and up-and-running tech-wise?

Edit: The world is in a situation where they needed to escape quickly, so they left without a plan other than “build some ships and leave Earth.” A good example of the ships are the ones from Wall-e; they’re not entirely realistic, but neither is horrific monsters crawling out of the Earth to punish humanity for the actions of the few.

I’m defining “the rich” as people who made their money exploiting others, whether they themselves became the richest man in the world by barely paying workers or their ancestors sent men and children to mine coal and die while they made all the money off of it. That’s why they left first; they deemed themselves more important than people with less money than them and they were taking their wealth to the stars. The only reason some regular people got to leave as well was due to the governments of the world offering to pitch in to speed up building in return for more people to be able to escape.

The regular people who got to leave were chosen randomly; let’s say 35% of people from each country who were healthy, currently children or able to have children, and willing to leave any family members not chosen behind could leave Earth. Obviously, some people died between being chosen and leaving, so to make more money they created a lottery system to fill spots. Most of the main character’s coworkers who weren’t already chosen bought tickets, and by a stroke of luck a lot of them got on. That’s why he was able to go from intern to radio host so quickly.

The story isn’t about the people who left, it’s about the people who are still on Earth, trying to retain some normalcy while dealing with being left on a planet that has been deemed “unsafe” to continue human life on. They end up dealing with the punishment meant for the oil barons and other people who destroyed the environment for monetary gains.

I’m trying to ask if if humanity could keep current technology running somewhat or if they would have to go back to using some manual tools and more human labor and focus electricity on things deemed important, such as hospital equipment, tv and radio for news, and lights.

Comment: The problem here is that you're treating the rich and the famous as though they were homogeneous groups, when you really need to ask why the individuals became rich and/or famous.  If they inherited wealth, or became famous from being rap artists or reality show stars, then the Earth might well (IMHO, anyway) function better without them.

Comment: This is unanswerable in its current state. Please define "a chunk of the Earth's population", and "a certain percentage". You example shows an INTERN being left in charge of a radio station. That would require removing some 50%++ of the staff?

Comment: Why are they leaving? You won't have so many people wanting to leave without their future on earth being a very difficult one. Wealth means nothing in space - once they get to the new planet they'll have to work like everyone else. An imminent asteroid impact or something is going to change how people act once the space ship has left.

Comment: How many people left? Why would anybody believe that the rich and famous (as a group) do anything useful? Why would anybody believe that politicians (as a group) do anything not harmful? I just don't see how this question could be answered: it is extremely vague, and proceeds from a strange position. (For example, the question states that because so many policians left, *"he governmental structure wouldn't be the same"*. First, this does not follow -- why wouldn't elections work? Why would a country's *"governmental structure"* have to change just because a new party gets elected?)

Comment: Those left behind are not just the telephone sanitizers?

Comment: On further thought, it appears that you might be re-writing Ayn Rand's "Atlas Shrugged" with added spaceships :-)

Comment: Cambodia is not doing too badly nowadays it seems. Your spaceship plot is of course a lot more human than Pol Pot's autogenocide.

Comment: And before anyone asks why he was left behind, he is a Trans man who has already had metoidioplasty, so he cannot have children.

Comment: This is in the VTR queue. I can't vote to reopen. This is a [high concept question](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4868) and as such is off-topic. In other words, you've posited the theme of an entire book and then asked us to write it for you. From the [help/on-topic], "When asking questions keep in mind that the goal of the site is to help you build your world, not to tell your story." Please ask about rules of your world, not the stories in your world.

Comment: I personally voted to reopen because the question is narrower than it seems. It doesn't ask "what would happen to the world if...", it asks "would the world function normally if..." - that's a much more limited answer scope because it doesn't include minute details, only grand effects of the economic kind. Of course "rich people" is less well-defined but an answer can explore that; changing it to e.g. the richest 1% of the world is not going to make the concept any narrower. I do think some extra details on how many non-rich people would leave are welcome, but not enough to close the question.

Comment: If 1% is gone, notjing will change it will be replaced by another 1%. If 10% is gone we may have some difficulties short time, but nothjng drastic, wwii example. 50% gone, that one is unprecidented, but it will be over in few decades (20-40years) based on indirect conclusions. Society, it's one of it main functiins to be robust enough against such events, maybe it indirect cinsequence of other things, but. // VTO it is a legit question which can be answered using rationale logic and history and science and society as per help center.

Comment: *"I’m defining “the rich” as people who made their money exploiting others"* So wouldn't the world just be better off without them, if their defining characteristic is that they exploit people rather than help them? But I doubt that your radio station would be lacking so many staff that an intern would be left in charge, if it is only the vultures who are gone.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What I'm confused about is not whether the Earth could survive, but *why it would be the rich and famous are the ones who leave*. In my eyes, **they'd send the working class ahead of them** to find a place and prepare it and make it luxurious instead of leaving everything behind and shooting off through space toward a nebulous and probably quite hazardous future. In one of his books, I believe Asimov talks about a rich and decadent society, instead of exploring planets directly, wants to send robots ahead of them to do all the terraforming, building, etc. so that when they arrive they have a ready-made world.

*Putting that aside*, let's answer your question. First off, what reasons might cause the Earth to have trouble if the rich and famous leave? Presumably, they're not taking all their stuff with them ([Every Gram Counts](http://www.projectrho.com/public_html/rocket/basicdesign.php#id--Every_Gram_Counts)), so **there's no question of resources being lost by Earth**. The only resource that might go down is that of people who are industrious and inventive and able to lead. I know that assumes that the rich are necessarily more so of those things, which isn't true, but I'm assuming a worst-case scenario for Earth.

So, all of Earth's most industrious and ingenious people have left the planet. Does this cause problems? When I look at history, the sense I get is that **humanity always rises to the challenge.** All the revolutions and uprisings and people working their way up from nothing show that people who are not rich or famous can still be great leaders and lead to strong output from Earth's resources.

And even if no one rises up and takes control, **within one generation the problem will be fixed**. People rich from birth are not necessarily smarter or better leaders than ones who are poor from birth. Even if all the world's great leaders have left, new ones will be born. (I do want to mention, there might not be as good education available with the rich gone, but I'll let you figure out how you want to deal with that in your story)

Okay, so we've established that Earth can survive and manage pretty well without the rich. But that's not what your question asked. You asked if they can function "normally" and to that my answer is a resounding **no**. If "normal" is meaning "as they used to" then that is just simply not going to happen. When the people find themselves in power, things change. When the people took power in the French revolution, nobody called what they did "normal." They're going to change a lot, but I'm going to leave it up to you to tell the story of *what* they change. :)

But I would expect that major trends will re-emerge, again, within a generation. There will be a new rich class, a new working class. And don't forget, the industrious humans who take charge might not do so out of selflessness. They're probably being greedy and want more for themselves. There will be rich and poor again.

I hope that helps answer your question.

Comment: I was composing my answer while you were. Mine is slightly different (so I'm leaving it) but a decent amount of overlap. +1

Comment: Rich and decadent society? Why would we NOT send von Neumann machines to remake the universe to our liking?

Comment: Exactly ;) It's not rich people who'll be going and colonizing weird and dangerous worlds. And somehow I can definitely see them sending von Neumann probes.

Answer (score 12):

### **Proletariat!:**

Your question is predicated on the assumption that the functional elite of the world are irreplaceable and that the world will come to a screeching halt unless they are there. I have to disagree with this assumption, and suggest while there may be short-term disruptions in how things work, we are still talking about humans and the same infrastructure.

- If the construction of the ships has drained away irreplaceable resources (like the world economy depends on neodymium, and the entire supply is flying off into space) or the diversion of resources is so great that the global economy is on the verge of collapse, then the resulting global economy may be seriously compromised.
- Genetic fitness for colonization is a highly subjective evaluation, and is rarely correlated with wealth or success. Famously, the crowned heads of Europe had serious problems with hemophilia. The kind of in-breeding more common among self-selecting elites is IMOHO more likely to result in genetically undesirable traits like the exaggerated features of the noble families of ancient Egypt.
- Most wealth is based ultimately on the possession of non-portable goods and systems. While the rich can all pile into spaceships and fly away, the factories, corporations, and real estate their wealth is based on is not able to be moved. So literally, they can't take it with them. Unless you have conditions on the Earth deteriorating seriously, I question if the rich would abandon their wealth for an uncertain future in a distant star system. Traditionally, the rich were a tiny part of a colonization, relying on an influx of labor to give value to the colonies they tried to then own. Even if the Earth was decaying, some would choose to be elites in bad conditions rather than commoners in a new place. Better to reign in Hell than serve in Heaven.
- Because the wealth and means of production would be left behind, the resources to support the resulting population would be expanded as wealth was redistributed and the burden on the environment lessened by the reduction in the population. There would likely be a short-term brain-drain of highly educated workers and professors. The knowledge would still exist, and enough educated genetic rejects would still exist to maintain the educational system. It might even create opportunities for intelligent people among minorities and the poor to rise up and make better lives for themselves.

Comment: Nice, I had forgotten about the resources to build the ships. I guess, though, if it's only the rich leaving that probably wouldn't put a huge drain on the world resources, unless it's some extremely rare element needed for ships, which would limit the remaining population's ability to travel to space, but not much else since we've survived pretty well without it till now.

Comment: @Benjamin another important point is that wealth isn't a large silo full of cash, but ownership of productive capital, infrastructure and the means to enforce that ownership. If Bezos went whizzing off to the stars, what would prevent everyone else just taking his stuff?

Comment: @DrMcCleod Yeah, I was wrapping that up in my statement that they're probably leaving resources behind them. But I am glad this answer said it more clearly.

Answer (score 2):

**Depends on your definiton of "normal" ...**

*Some* of the rich and famous are famous for being famous (reality TV stars), rich because they inherited it.

*Some* of the rich and famous have earned their wealth and fame by doing things we could do without if we had to, even if that would diminish out society. Writers. Sports stars. Music stars. Actors.

*Many* of the somewhat rich and somewhat famous are rich because they do things well that are necessary for society as we know it. Corporate lawyers. CEOs. Heads of government. University deans. Brain surgeons. There is a skill to getting thousands, tens of thousands of people to work towards the same goal.

Take a company with 1,000 software engineers, 100 project managers, and 100 clerical staff. Take away the 100 project managers. Productivity *will* drop because the software engineers are not trained project managers. Over time it might creep up again, as people step into the gap, but then you have a company with 950 software engineers, 100 project managers, 50 clerical workers. Were those managers among your "rich and famous"?

Likewise in government. Career civil service are trained to *implement* policy, and even to *suggest* policy to the elected leaders. They are not trained to *build the necessary consensus* to make everybody happy with either building the motorway through the protected wetlands, or not building it and routing traffic through the city center, and then pushing a bad compromise through.

Imagine a store that got some of the merchandise from overseas. A shipment is held in a customs snafu and the clerks on either side go "you owe us" -- "don't" -- "do" -- "liar, liar, pants on fire." They *need* the corporate lawyers specializing in international commerce.

**The idea that those highly-paid professionals wouldn't be missed is populist nonsense.**

Comment: So to paraphrase Winston Churchill, 'Law, law, is better than war, war.'

Comment: @DrMcCleod, what war? All the generals and colonels and majors are gone, which leaves captains to run the shop ...

Comment: Your merchandise from overseas example is backwards.  Without the clerks and upper layers of bureaucracy, there wouldn't be any need for customs.  Buying something from Tokyo would be no different than buying it from (for Americans) Toledo or Tokyo.

Answer (score 1):

Never mind what happens on Earth; I'm having trouble comprehending the basic logistics of the evacuation.

"A few ships" are going to carry "a chunk" of Earth's 10 billion people away and then supposedly return for the rest.

What!???

- How big are those ships?
- How fast can they go?
- Where are they going?
- How long will the trip take?
- How are all these people going to survive at the destination? Especially when most of them have no useful practical skills.

I can't see the answers to *any* of those questions being in the least believable.

And all that is only the trigger for the *real* story, which sounds like it's going to be even more ridiculous.

---

This story deals with far far too many things on far far too big a scale. In the real world it just wouldn't make sense, and as fiction it is too complicated to handle without making it obvious that it *is* being handled by the author.

Scale it down. Make it a large corporation or a small country, with the rich and powerful moving to Brazil to escape justice when the financial collapse happens.

If you have a good story, it can be told just as well in that situation, without all the totally unnecessary window dressing.

---

Following up on @Hagen von Eitzen's reference ("*Those left behind are not just the telephone sanitizers?*"), If all the rich and famous suddenly disappeared, except in a few isolated situations it wouldn't really make much of a difference, and certainly not a negative one. Corporations and governments are designed to withstand unexpected changes of leadership; someone is always ready to move up the ladder to fill the vacancy.

Comment: The ships can be as big as you want because its Sci-Fi/Horror and the question is only tagged reality-check because I’m asking about the reality of part of the population leaving. They don’t know where they’re going; they just wanted off Earth. And no, it would be impossible to survive to the destination, because it would take a very long time to find a planet they could live on and ruin again, which is why they focused on people who could have offspring. They’ll just wander the stars until they die or a group of people take over the ship and try to head back.

Answer (score 0):

Just look at Soviets what happened with them when they get rid of the rich.
First they sent the rich on other world by shot them and then they shared the land to peasants, and they nationalized the factories.
Because the nationalized factories went bad, they took the land from now prosperous peasants and they nationalized it. The land was not worked properly and they had several famines. 3 million people died in Ukraine, the soviet breadbasket.
As it is said above not all rich people are created equal. Some inherited the wealth, some broke he law to have it, some were cozy with politicians,some were lucky, but some were smarter and hard working as others.
So don't throw away the baby with the water.
Some see inequality as the root of all evil. For those I recommend to visit Barcelona and see works of Gaudi, and remember that everything was financed by a rich guy called Guell.
If we stop comparing with others, we will have enough resources for all, for a decent life.
Lack of rights determines that you work more in improper conditions, not the wealth inequality.

Comment: Not really the same.  The problem with the Soviets was not that they got rid of one set of rich, but that they then prevented anyone else from taking their places.  (Except by becoming Party apparatchiks, of course.) Since there was no productive way to become rich, everyone stayed poor.